# angularjs ui bootstrap tab do not close properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have two tabs, the second has a close icon.

i want that when i close the second tab, the first to be selected automatically

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.tab1 = {
            title: 'Dynamic Title 1',
            content: 'Dynamic content 1',
            active: true
        };

    $scope.tab2 = {
            title: 'Dynamic Title 2',
            content: 'Dynamic content 2',
            active: true,
            show: true
        };

    $scope.removeTab1 = function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $scope.tab2.show = false;
        $scope.tab1.active = true;
    };
});
```

here's the plunkr :
https://plnkr.co/edit/j1Ik9zVC5XCO0ge4?preview

How can i achieve that ?
thanks in advance.